# How to get route name YAML Block/Form?

Tags: 8

I am not a coder, how can I get a route name from YAML Form (ex.Contact form) and put it to YAML Block?
Is there a route name UI like path auto UI?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Drupal routes aren't display in a UI anywhere, but you can look them up in a database client (e.g. PHPMyAdmin). The route defnitions are stored in the `router` table. The `name`, `path`, & `pattern_outline` columns should be enough to search for what you're looking for. The name column contains the unique ID for each route. In your case, `contact.site_page` is the name of the contact form route.

Comment: Thank you Shown, what is different using route name instead path url?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but the YAML block uses the route name. It's a unique identifier for route which can be accessed through the Drupal API.